# ODBC Data Source Admin does not list newly created DB created in MySQL Workbench 5.2.43

Tags: mysql, odbc

My question relates completely to a Windows Environment.

I have MySQL Workbench version 5.2.43 installed on a 64 bit Windows 2008 Server. This server houses the lane0_qa database. I am using Qlikview installed on a 64 Bit Windows XP machine to represent graphical information from the lane_0qa database. Connectivity between the Qlikview host and the QA database appears to be working fine.

Using MY SQL Workbench, I recently created a new database on the Win2k8 server named **new_schema**. I have granted the same privileges to the "**root**" user on this database that were also assigned to the QA database.

Using ODBC Data Source Administrator on the 2k8 Server, I was able to create a System DSN named **test** with localhost as the TCP/IP server. Entering the user as root, I am able to see the "**new_schema**" database in MySQL Connector/ODBC Data Source Configuration window

However, on the XP machine with Qlikview, when adding the same test DSN in ODBC Data Source Configuration, I do not see "new_schema" listed in the drop down menu.

How can I get the "new_schema" database to appear on the XP machine?

Comment: My guess is that your XP machine is connecting as a different MySQL user than the Win2k8 server is. You say you granted privileges to "root" user; we'd assume then that this "root" user does not have global privileges on all databases, e.g. `SELECT ON *.*`. A MySQL user is identified by a combination of `host` and `user`; user `'root'@'127.0.0.1'` is different from `'root'@'localhost'` and different from `'root'@'%'`. Maybe you did not grant privileges to the "root" user used by the XP machine. That's my guess.

Comment: I executed the command below to grant all rights to the user root connecting from the XP machine                                          GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON new_schema.* TO 'root'@'ip_address_of_2k8_server';                                    Just for grins I also flushed privileges. The new_schema db still didn't appear. Manually entering the db name and hitting test throws "Unknown DB" error message. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the database I had the IP address set to was on a different machine. Human error. Sorry. Entering the correct IP address of the 2k8 server displayed the new_schema table in the ODBC Admin Panel.