# ODBC data source admin lists only default schemas

Tags: mysql, odbc, workbench

I’m very new in MySQL (but have some experience in MS SQL and Postgres). Our firm decided to move out data to MySQL server. So, I’ve established connection with SSH credentials (using PuTTY) as “root” user.

To log into Workbench 8.0 and ODBC (Connector/ODBC 8.0) I use IP “localhost” with 3306 port. But in Workbench I can see all data bases and tables which were created by me or colleagues, and in ODBC are visible only default schemas: information_schema, mysql, performance_schema, sys.

There was discussed a similar issue [ODBC Data Source Admin does not list newly created DB created in MySQL Workbench 5.2.43](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830240/odbc-data-source-admin-does-not-list-newly-created-db-created-in-mysql-workbench), but I clearly don’t understand is it my case. I used my computer's IP address to log in and it still didn't work. Just not a good prospect to send files and links to the IT department, so that they are already uploaded to the server.